# What is a similar relation for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{B_n(0!F(s),1!F(2s),\dots,(n-1)!F(ns))}{n!}}$

Tags: symmetric-polynomials

A result of the exponential formula is 
$$\exp{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{B_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)}{n!}x^n}$$
Now define 
$$F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(t_n)^x}$$
for some set of real numbers $\{t_1,t_2,\dots\}$.

I can show that for $s\gt0$
$$\exp{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{-F(ns)}
{n}}\right)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{B_n(-0!F(s),-1!F(2s),\dots,-(n-1)!F(ns))}{n!}}$$
where $B_n(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the complete exponential Bell polynomial.
This equation is what we would get by substituting in the first formula, but without the $x$ variables.  But by the same reasoning, we unexpectedly have the following inequality.
$$\exp{\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{F(ns)}{n}}\right)}\ne\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{B_n(0!F(s),1!F(2s),\dots,(n-1)!F(ns))}{n!}}$$
I can't figure out how to get an expression for the right hand side that looks somewhat like the left hand side. If there is a way, how do I get it?  I'm hoping for a similar relationship as the one with negative terms.